# The file flint.exe could not be found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use python 2.7 in windows 7.
I want to call a exe
 file in the folder and get the output.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'flint.exe ./'

def run_cmd2file(cmd):
   fdout = open("summary.log",'a')
   fderr = open("file_err.log",'a')
   p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=fdout, stderr=fderr, shell=True)
   if p.poll():
      return
   p.wait()
   return


   run_cmd2file(cmd)
```

But the error shows the file flint.exe could not be found. I do put it in the python file folder.

Comment: Could you try `subprocess.Popen("ls -la", stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, shell=True)` to check if the executable is present in cwd?:)

Comment: the return value is None, what should I do?

Comment: Please give the exact error message that you get.

Comment: Is flint.exe in your system PATH ?